# Programmatically scroll Sencha Touch Ext.Panel to anchor element

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a scrollable panel that shows content larger than the screen

```
new Ext.Panel({
  scroll: 'vertical',
  html: 'very larger content here with an anchor. <p id="anchor">'
});
```

and (on a click event) I want to (programmatically) scroll the panel to a certain HTML element . Preferably even animated. In jquery I would do something along the lines of

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out what you can do is

```
function scrollIntoView(el,cmp) {
  var dy = cmp.scroller.offset.y + el.getY() - cmp.body.getY();
  cmp.scroller.setOffset({x:0, y:-dy}, true);
}

scrollIntoView(Ext.fly('anchor'), Ext.getCmp('panel'));
```

which probably is quite similar to what `scrollIntoView()` does internally - haven't looked at that code though. But it's without animation.

Comment: this works great. In Sencha 2 the first line of that method now needs to look like this: cmp.getScrollable().getScroller().position.y + el.getY() - cmp.body.getY()

Comment: In Sencha 2 there is a .scrollTo method which is better.  See: http://docs-devel.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.scroll.Scroller-method-scrollTo

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `setOffset()` function of the `scroller` object.

Example:
You have your original panel:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
  scroll: 'vertical',
  html: 'very larger content here with an anchor. <p id="anchor">'
});
```

To scroll this element, you just call

```
myPanel.scroller.setOffset(0,20)
```

You can add a third animation parameter as documented [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Draggable-method-setOffset), but I haven't tested that one yet.

Comment: Nice. That's even better. Unfortunately when you touch the panel (after the animation) to drag it, it jumps back to the original position.

Comment: Actually turns out that was just because the scroller had to scroll further as the content allows. So it jumped back to a valid position. With proper content it works fine. Cool.

Comment: myPanel.scroller is undefined in sencha touch 2.4: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOffset' of undefined @Edward B

Answer (score 0):

This has been problematic for Sencha Touch as far as I can tell, note that there is no `.scrollIntoView()` method in Touch like in the other Sencha frameworks. It can be done by integrating [**iScroll**](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-3-5-adds-scrolltoelement) with Touch though, that will give you iScroll methods to accomplish it and make your scrolling more native. [**Here**](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/11/extjs-and-iscroll-scrolling-ext-containers-on-touch-devices-ipad-iphone-etc-using-iscro) is an example of how it was done.